# Python3: Attempting to use a list to "filter" through a JSON file in order to retrieve selected information

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I am attempting to solve this issue - I have a text file full of `attributes`. Like so... (in reality there would around a hundred of lines of attributes)

```
textfile = Color
           Width
           Height
           Software
           Comment
           Size
```

I then have another 100 `json` files that look like this:

```
[{
    "Title": "painting",
    "Artist":"Pablo Picasso",
    "Width":400,
    "Height": 400,
    "Name": "test-painting",
    "Comment":"none"
}]
```

I would like to try and "filter" the `json` files so they will only display the defined `attributes` in textfile. For example, I would want the example `json` file to look like this after applying the textfile as a filter.

```
[{
    "Width":400,
    "Height":400,
    "Comment":"none"
}]
```

So this filter would basically only display what I define in textfile. I have tried this so far unsuccessfully.

```
import os,sys
import json

attributes = [word.strip('\n').split(',')
     for word in open("textfile", 'r').readlines()]

for filename in os.listdir(.)
    with open(filename) as jsonfile:
         data = json.load(jsonfile)
         for line in data:
            for a in attribute:
                if a in line:
                   print(line)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What was unsuccessful about your attempt? It certainly looks along the right lines but you're not taking action on a match (`print()` basically does nothing).

Comment: with open(filename) as jsonfile: 

I guess you forgot to specify 'r' after 'filename' in the open arguments.

Comment: How do you differentiate between the JSON files and the attributes text file? By extension?

Comment: So for attributes, I took the txt file and made it as a list, and I am getting the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an issue with the way the attributes file was being read.
Here is some code that will extract json objects based on an attributes filter file.

Example run.

```
./53619747.py -h
usage: 53619747.py [-h]
                   attributes-text-path json-input-directory
                   json-output-directory

positional arguments:
  attributes-text-path
  json-input-directory
  json-output-directory

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

./53619747.py attributes.txt input-json output-json
```

Example output.

```
./53619747.py attributes.txt input-json output-json
('attributes.txt', 'input-json', 'output-json')
[['Color'], ['Width'], ['Height'], ['Software'], ['Comment'], ['Size']]
['Color', 'Width', 'Height', 'Software', 'Comment', 'Size']
input-json/0001.json
[{u'Comment': u'none', u'Name': u'test-painting', u'Artist': u'Pablo Picasso', u'Title': u'painting', u'Height': 400, u'Width': 400}]
{u'Comment': u'none', u'Name': u'test-painting', u'Artist': u'Pablo Picasso', u'Title': u'painting', u'Height': 400, u'Width': 400}
(u'Comment', u'none')
(u'Name', u'test-painting')
(u'Artist', u'Pablo Picasso')
(u'Title', u'painting')
(u'Height', 400)
(u'Width', 400)
{u'Comment': u'none', u'Width': 400, u'Height': 400}
output-json/0001.json
```

Contents of 53619747.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import os
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("attributes-text-path")
parser.add_argument("json-input-directory")
parser.add_argument("json-output-directory")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print(args['attributes-text-path'],args['json-input-directory'],args['json-output-directory'])

attributes = [word.strip('\n').split(',')
     for word in open(args['attributes-text-path'], 'r').readlines()]

print(attributes)
# [['Color'], ['Width'], ['Height'], ['Software'], ['Comment'], ['Size']]

attributes = []
with open(args['attributes-text-path'], 'r') as attributes_file_handler:
    for line in attributes_file_handler:
        # add the line minus the carriage return to attributes
        attributes.append(line.strip())

print(attributes)
# ['Color', 'Width', 'Height', 'Software', 'Comment', 'Size']

for filename in os.listdir(args['json-input-directory']):

    valid_json_file = False
    input_json_objects = []
    input_path = os.path.join(args['json-input-directory'],filename)

    print(input_path)

    with open(input_path) as input_json_file_handler:
        try:
            input_json_objects = json.load(input_json_file_handler)
            valid_json_file = True
            print(input_json_objects)
        except Exception as exception:
            print(exception)

    if valid_json_file:
        output_path = os.path.join(args['json-output-directory'],filename)
        results = []
        for item in input_json_objects:
            print(item)
            result = {}
            attribute_found = False
            for key in item.keys():
                print(key,item[key])
                if key in attributes:
                    result[key] = item[key]
                    attribute_found = True
            if attribute_found:
                print(result)
                results.append(result)    

        print(output_path)          
        with open(output_path,'w') as output_json_file_handler:
            output_json_file_handler.write(json.dumps(results,indent=4))
```

Comment: adjusted my code and edited it with your suggestion, and it worked great. Thanks again!